# Trouble with swift optionals when trying to use a URL string

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm trying to load a web page when the an annotation's callout is tapped, so I'm attempting a switch statement to check the annotation title then display the correct webpage. However as a swift beginner, the optionals are giving me quite a bit of trouble. I've tried several variations but keep getting errors. Here's my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let restaurant = view.annotation as! Restaurants
    let placeName = restaurant.title!
    let placeInfo = restaurant.info


    switch placeName {
    case "Chili's":
        if let urlString = "http://www.chilis.com" as? String {
            let chilisUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: chilisUrl!))
        }
    case "George's":
        if let urlString = "http://www.georges-ny.com" as? String {
            let georgesUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: georgesUrl!))
        }
    case "TGI Friday's":
        if let urlString = "https://www.tgifridays.com" as? String {
            let fridaysUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: fridaysUrl!))
        }
    case "Reserve Cut":
        if let urlString = "http://reservecut.com" as? String {
            let rcUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: rcUrl!))
        }
    case "Bill's Bar & Burger":
        if let urlString = "http://www.billsbarandburger.com" as? String {
            let billsUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: billsUrl!))
        }
    default:
        if let urlString = "http://www.oharaspubnyc.com" as? String {
            let oharasUrl = URL(string: urlString)
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: oharasUrl!))
        }
    }



    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    self.view = webView
}
```

I've tried just using the URL directly like `self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: "http://reservecut.com" as! URL))`

and

```
let rcUrl = URL(string: "http://reservecut.com")
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: rcUrl!))
```

but those gave me problems as well.

How can I safely unwrap (?) and use the URL strings here? And I guess it's also worth asking if there's a cleaner/more efficient way of going about this? I thought about using a dictionary but figured it would end up being more code in the long run. Anyway thanks for any advice!

Comment: For starters, why are you casting a string to a string? `if let urlString = "http://www.chilis.com" as? String` It'll always succeed...

Comment: Please, when posting a question about errors, it is important that you question includes the complete error message(s) as well as clearly points out the lines causing the errors.

Comment: `"www.http://georges-ny.com"`? Really??

Comment: @matt Apologies for the typo. Don't think it deserves a downvote on the question though.

Comment: When asking about your code, you should copy your real code and paste it into SO. However, the downvote is for the nature of the question: saying "are giving me quite a bit of trouble", "keep getting errors", "gave me problems as well", is not a SO question. It is totally unclear what the issue is here.

Comment: Fair enough. It is my code copied/pasted from my project, to be perfectly honest I have no idea how that particular typo came to be. But I'll keep that in mind when asking my next question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first if statements in your code is pointless and does nothing - there's nothing optional about it, hence nothing to unwrap, and "http://www.chilis.com" is already a string so nothing to cast let alone conditionally cast.

Converting a string to a URL could fail so that is where your if let should go

```
        if let chilisUrl = URL(string: "http://www.chilis.com")
        {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: chilisUrl))
        }
```

Comment: I just tried this and got an error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the `self.webview.load` line

Comment: @KingTim Then `self.webview` is `nil`. Check your outlets.

Comment: Ok, I was forgetting `webView = WKWebView()` in `viewDidLoad`. This seems to be working now for https addresses, I had to go into the Custom target properties and add "Allow Arbitrary Loads) for the http ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`URL` instances are returned as optional values because the URL may be invalid. You need to unwrap it so that you can use it in the `URLRequest` initializer, which expects a non-optional value.

Therefore, something like this will work:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "www.google.com") else { fatalError("Invalid URL") }
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
webview.load(request)
```